# JavaScript chart webapp

Tags: web-apps, javascript, charts, csv

I'm looking for a webapp that allows me to code in JavaScript based on CSV files and create charts using one of the JavaScript charting libraries like plotly or highcharts.

Does such a thing exist?

I'm thinking of using jsbin or similar but am wondering if there's a more dedicated tool for it.

Comment: Why do you need a web app to code your chart using JavaScript instead of coding directly form you text editor or IDE?

Comment: @Dan. i wanted something that was quick and easy to share. There's a lot of stuff that a dedicated charting app can do to help that wouldn't be available in a text editor. I'm thinking of stuff like tableu and spotfire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) is a web application that allows you to create and share documents that contain live code, equations, visualizations and explanatory text. Google Colaboratory is Google's free Jupyter notebook environment that requires no setup and runs entirely in the cloud.

[IJavascript](https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript) is a JavaScript kernel for Jupyter Notebook. [3 Ways to Make Interactive Graphs in Jupyter Notebooks](https://web.archive.org/web/20170108084403/https://medium.com/@captain_eli/3-ways-to-make-interactive-graphs-in-jupyter-notebooks-154cbb4796a9) shows an example of a chart in Jupyter Notebook made with Plotly. On the same webpage is another example of a chart in Jupyter Notebook made with Python and PivotTable.js.

#### PivotTable.js

**Installation**

```
python -m pip install pivottablejs
```

**Usage**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("some_input.csv")

from pivottablejs import pivot_ui

pivot_ui(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://downrunner.com may suit your needs. It uses Google Charts under the covers. You create Markdown pages and then add special JSON like markup to create your charts.